# Is it ok to run long code inside onPause() in Android Activity?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, onpause

By "long code," I mean updating many rows of an SQLite database. I have already implemented this. But some users (just a few) are complaining that their data is not being updated. Apparently, the problem appears only when the users press the back button. Perhaps the Activity dies before completing the code inside onPause()? Is this a normal behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you mean you want to put a method inside `onPause`?

Answer (score 2):

Directly from [the documentation about the Activity lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle):

> onPause() execution is very brief, and does not necessarily afford enough time to perform save operations. For this reason, you should not use onPause() to save application or user data, make network calls, or execute database transactions; such work may not complete before the method completes. Instead, you should perform heavy-load shutdown operations during onStop(). For more information about suitable operations to perform during onStop(), see onStop(). For more information about saving data, see Saving and restoring activity state.

Basically: yes, you should not be doing any of that in `onPause`.

Comment: Thank you very much. The answer cannot be clearer. Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

No, you shouldn't call a heavy task (SQL Transactions) in `onPause()`.

However, what you can do is save the data as soon as it is changed.

I advise you to use `RoomDB` with `Kotlin Coroutines` which won't even block your UI.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll follow your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Your question do not clearly yet. You should be post your code and everyone can help you.

I suggest to use [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) or [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) to excute any task which need to be done. Do not put your task in your activity/view context. Because, activity/view can be destroy anytime that's you will be hard to control.